# Send email from async method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

If I'm trying to send an email immediately a new email has been confirmed, how to I go about it ?
The piece of code below is what I have in `ConfirmEmail` method. When I run the code, I get `Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on `await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(userId, "API", "API Code is: " + user.ApiCode);`

I think `UserManager.FindById` is not returning anything, but not sure how to go about it.

Any pointers/ideas will help.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
{
    if (userId == null || code == null)
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
    var result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);

    var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(userId, "API", "API Code is: " + user.ApiCode);

    return View(result.Succeeded ? "ConfirmEmail" : "Error");
}
```

Comment: My guess is that the User is not authenticated yet so User.Identity is null and hence the NullReferenceException. Have you tried var user = UserManager.FindById(userId); instead?

Comment: You haven't checked whether `user` is null before using it

Comment: have you debugged?. How did you implement the user sign in process? are you using your own MembershipProvider implementation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)

Comment: @KarelTamayo Can you create a proper answer? Your comment helped solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the info you provided I guess maybe the problem is that the user is not authenticated and therefore `User.Identity` will return null, hence the `NullReferenceException`.

You could try to fetch the user information with the id you're receiving in the action parameter `userId` instead.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
{
    if (userId == null || code == null)
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
    var result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);

    //var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    var user = UserManager.FindById(userId); //use the received parameter to get the user
    await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(userId, "API", "API Code is: " + user.ApiCode);

    return View(result.Succeeded ? "ConfirmEmail" : "Error");
}
```

Hope this helps!